# Facebook image upload works but facebook video upload fails

Tags: facebook, image, video, upload, unity-game-engine

I'm struggling to do a facebook video upload.
The error I get when implementing my code after getting a token is 400 bad request.

I am able to login and get a token. 
I set the facebook app with permissions that should allow video uploading and have checked that those permissions are correct. 
I can also post an image using the same method but for some reason posting the video fails with the 400 error.

The code below is from Unity3d. The code below basically does a POST and adds the video data to the post. Like I said it works for an image file but not video.

```
    private WWW w;
    public void FBPostVideo(){
    Debug.Log("in the fbpostvideo ienumerator");
    var moviebytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Application.persistentDataPath+"/screenrecording.mp4");
    Debug.Log(moviebytes.Length);
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    var video_desc="walkingthedog";
    var video_title="dogwalk";
    var access_token=token;
    form.AddBinaryData("file", moviebytes, "myvideo");
    var formurl="https://graph-video.facebook.com/me/videos?title="+video_title
+ "&description=" +video_desc + "&"+token;
    Debug.Log(formurl);
    WWW w = new WWW(formurl, form);
    StartCoroutine(waitForMovie(w));
    }

    public IEnumerator waitForMovie(WWW w){
    yield return w;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(w.error))
    Debug.Log(w.error);
    else
    Debug.Log("Finished Uploading");
    }

    *

    *The php suggested code:
    <?php
    $app_id = "YOUR_APP_ID";
    $app_secret = "YOUR_APP_SECRET";
    $my_url = "YOUR_POST_LOGIN_URL";
    $video_title = "YOUR_VIDEO_TITLE";
    $video_desc = "YOUR_VIDEO_DESCRIPTION";

    $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

    if(empty($code)) {
    $dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="
    . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
    . "&scope=publish_stream";
    echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
    }

    $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="
    . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
    . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
    . "&code=" . $code;
    $access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);

    $post_url = "https://graph-video.facebook.com/me/videos?"
    . "title=" . $video_title. "&description=" . $video_desc
    . "&". $access_token;

    echo '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action=" '.$post_url.' "
    method="POST">';
    echo 'Please choose a file:';
    echo '<input name="file" type="file">';
    echo '<input type="submit" value="Upload" />';
    echo '</form>';
    ?>*
```